# How to get the maximum value of N past observations

Tags: r, vector

Suppose *y*<sub>*t*</sub> is a time series. What I want is *x*<sub>*t*</sub> = max(*y*<sub>*t*</sub>,*y*<sub>*t* -1</sub>,...,*y*<sub>*t* - *N*</sub>). My code is

```
x<-unlist(lapply(seq_along(y),function(i)max(y[seq.int(max(1L,i-N),i)])))
```

This code uses `lapply` and there are repetitive reads, so I think it isn't taking full advantage of SIMD features of the processor. Is there a faster solution?

Comment: Do you mean like `cummax(y)`?

Comment: cummax gives max for all past values. I need the max of past N values.

Comment: Sorry, of course. What about `zoo::rollmax`?

Comment: Good. I think this is what I want. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `roll_max` from `RcppRoll`

```
library(RcppRoll)
roll_max(v1, n=3)
```

#### data

```
v1 <- 1:10
```